# How to make this code shorter and better

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

How to clean and make better following "scrappy" php code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::init();
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$productList = array(
    array(),
    array(),
    array()
);
$count = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$name = array();
$qty = array();
$price = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $name[$i] = $cart[$i]->getProduct()->getName();
    $qty[$i] = $cart[$i]->getQty();
    $price[$i] = $cart[$i]->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $productList[$i] = array(
        $name[$i],
        $qty[$i],
        $price[$i]
    );
}
print_r($productList);
```

I want to know, how to beautify such frament. May be I should use shorter array initialization form, some standard php functions in this case and so on.

Comment: This belongs at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this approach is a bit better

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("app/Mage.php");

function setData($acc, $item)
{
    $acc[] = [
    $item->getProduct()->getName(),
    $item->getQty(),
    $item->getProduct()->getPrice()
];
return $acc;
}

Mage::init();
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", ["name" => "frontend"]);
print_r(array_reduce(Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getQuote()
->getAllVisibleItems(), "setData", []));
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::init();

Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$productList = array();

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productList[]=array($item->getName(),$item->getQty(),$item->getPrice());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');
$storeId = 0;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId));

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

foreach ($products as $product) {   

        print_r($product->getdata());

        }
```

Comment: You code doesn't fit my needs. 
Because I want to collect product properties mentioned above from third party shell script. Nor from magento module.